# Git push existing repo to a new and different remote repo server?

Tags: git, github

Say I have a repository on [git.fedorahosted.org](http://git.fedorahosted.org/git/?p=rhq/rhq.git;a=summary) and I want to clone this into my account at github to have my own playground aside from the more "official" repo on fedorahosted.
What would be the steps to initially copy that over?
Within github there is this nice "fork" button, but I can't use this for obvious reasons.

And how would I track changes in the fedorahosted repo into the github one?

Answer (score 1040, accepted):

1. Create a new repo at github.
2. Clone the repo from fedorahosted to your local machine.
3. `git remote rename origin upstream`
4. `git remote add origin URL_TO_GITHUB_REPO`
5. `git push origin master`

Now you can work with it just like any other github repo. To pull in patches from upstream, simply run `git pull upstream master && git push origin master`.

GitHub has recently renamed its `master` branch to `main` so (depending on whether your branch is called `master` or `main`) in step 5 you might have to use `git push origin main` and for pulling patches from upstream `git pull upstream main && git push origin main`, otherwise you will receive an error message.

Comment: There is no reason to rename the original origin, just call the new play-ground something else.

Comment: @tcaswell Technically no, but it is a strong convention that `origin` points to the canonical remote location. In this case, the github location would presumably be the canonical.

Comment: I would consider 'upstream' to be the canonical location, but I think this is start to split hairs.

Comment: Maybe I should post a different question but I think you guys are discussing what I want. I'd like to add a new remote, not replace the existing one so I can continue to pull from the old repository but push any changes to the new one.

Comment: @ThatAintWorking You probably should open a new question, but in short - you can add any number of remotes with the command `git remote add`. You can then push to one of them by explicitly stating the remote in `git push`. E.g. `git push foobar master` to push the current branch to `master` on remote `foobar`.

Comment: GitHub gives you a service for importing automatically from Subversion server repo: [Importing from SVN](https://help.github.com/articles/importing-from-subversion/)

Comment: does not push cloned files

Comment: Nice solution but with an important shortcoming: the `upstream` remote repo meta data is only available in the local "workarea" repo; not the new remote repo.  In other words, if I clone the new repo somewhere else (`git clone URL_TO_GITHUB_REPO` to follow example) and try `git remote show upstream` I get: "fatal: 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository".  Hence I've lost crucial ability to do things like `git pull upstream master`.  Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @sxc731Not really. Github has their own internal tracking of "forks" between repositories, but the way that git is constructed, means that all repository clones are fully autonomous. Once you fork, there is really no canonical master, apart from whatever convention you uphold.

Comment: When I do it like this and don't use **"--mirror push"** from [mob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18751888/5195032), I always get `error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/username/testrep.git'`

Comment: Didn't push all my branches, just master. The mirror answer worked for all the branches

Comment: Also ... remember to recover tags: "git push --tags"

Comment: For "error: failed to push some refs to 'https://..." You can use "git push -f origin master"

Comment: This answer worked great for me. Instead of renaming origin, I just `git remote add new-remote-name URL_TO_NEW_GITHUB_REPO` and pushed to it `git push new-remote-name branch-name`

Comment: where in these codes is there an equivalent command to 'add' and 'commit' like it would be for a push from a local repo? or does the mere setting of the two remotes (an upstream one and then the downstream one (the new githubrepo)) sets up the those 'add' and 'commit' instructions?

Comment: Thanks @toelskn, I just used `git push origin main` in the 5th step and it worked for me. Also, I was able to upstream other branches instead of `main`.

Comment: Anyone know how will adding a new remote affect Visual Studio? - will both be available in the IDE

Answer (score 159):

There is a deleted answer on this question that had a useful link:  https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository

The gist is

```
0. create the new empty repository (say, on github)
1. make a bare clone of the repository in some temporary location
2. change to the temporary location
3. perform a mirror-push to the new repository
4. change to another location and delete the temporary location
```

OP's example:

On your local machine

```
$ cd $HOME
$ git clone --bare https://git.fedorahosted.org/the/path/to/my_repo.git
$ cd my_repo.git
$ git push --mirror https://github.com/my_username/my_repo.git
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf my_repo.git
```

Comment: What is the benefit of the bare clone and the mirror push over simply adding and pushing to another remote? Is it that all branches will be pushed and not just the current branch? (If so, this seems like a limitation of the accepted answer that should be noted.)

Comment: This was exactly the info I was looking for, the --bare / --mirror is usually what people want to perform! This is an important answer! Thanks

Comment: Great! Definetly the most correct answer on topic question. Thanks! If I don't do it like this, I always get `error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/username/testrep.git'`

Answer (score 79):

To push your existing repo into different, you need to:

1. Clone the original repo first.

   ```
   git clone https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/rhq/rhq.git
   ```
2. Push the cloned sources to your new repository:

   ```
   cd rhq
   git push https://github.com/user/example master:master
   ```

You may change `master:master` into `source:destination` branch.

---

If you want to push specific commit (branch), then do:

1. On the original repo, create and checkout a new branch:

   ```
   git checkout -b new_branch
   ```
2. Choose and reset to the point which you want to start with:

   ```
   git log # Find the interesting hash
   git reset 4b62bdc9087bf33cc01d0462bf16bbf396369c81 --hard
   ```

   Alternatively select the commit by `git cherry-pick` to append into existing HEAD.
3. Then push to your new repo:

   ```
   git push https://github.com/user/example new_branch:master
   ```

   <sup>If you're rebasing, use `-f` for force push (not recommended). Run `git reflog` to see history of changes.</sup>

Comment: the `git push ... old_branch_name:new_branch_name` allows you to push a feature branch from the old repository as the main branch in the new repository. Usefull!

Comment: This was the simplest way for me to do it.

Answer (score 64):

If you have Existing Git repository:

```
cd existing_repo
git remote rename origin old-origin
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/newproject
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```

Comment: Just to clarify, --all will push all branches

Comment: Great, very simple method to copy local repository to remote. Thanks.
Make sure the remote folder exists with a git repository. I used git init --bare on the remote server.

Comment: git push -u origin <branch-name> to push only the branch

Answer (score 34):

I found a solution using **set-url** which is *concise and fairly easy to understand*:

1. create a new repo at Github
2. `cd` into the existing repository on your local machine (if you haven't cloned it yet, then do this first)
3. `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user/example.git`
4. `git push -u origin master`

Answer (score 22):

Do you really want to simply push your local repository (with its local branches, etc.) to the new remote or do you really want to mirror the old remote (with all its branches, tags, etc) on the new remote?  If the latter here's a great blog on [How to properly mirror a git repository](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/05/how-to-properly-mirror-a-git-repository/).

I strongly encourage you to read the blog for some very important details, but the short version is this:

In a new directory run these commands:

```
git clone --mirror git@example.com/upstream-repository.git
cd upstream-repository.git
git push --mirror git@example.com/new-location.git
```

Comment: I think this is the link: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/05/how-to-properly-mirror-a-git-repository/

Answer (score 16):

Try this [How to move a full Git repository](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/01/totw-copying-a-full-git-repo/)

1. Create a local repository in the temp-dir directory using:

   git clone  temp-dir
2. Go into the temp-dir directory.
3. To see a list of the different branches in ORI do:

   ```
   git branch -a
   ```
4. Checkout all the branches that you want to copy from ORI to NEW using:

   ```
   git checkout branch-name
   ```
5. Now fetch all the tags from ORI using:

   ```
   git fetch --tags
   ```
6. Before doing the next step make sure to check your local tags and branches using the following commands:

   ```
   git tag


   git branch -a
   ```
7. Now clear the link to the ORI repository with the following command:

   ```
   git remote rm origin
   ```
8. Now link your local repository to your newly created NEW repository using the following command:

   ```
   git remote add origin <url to NEW repo>
   ```
9. Now push all your branches and tags with these commands:

   ```
   git push origin --all


   git push --tags
   ```
10. You now have a full copy from your ORI repo.

Comment: I liked this since it helped me duplicate a repo with a specific subset of branches, some of them being superfluous. I note that doing this with a GitHub-based repo seems to make it automatically create a PR for each non-default branch, and you can just close them; not sure if possible to stop the PRs from coming.

Answer (score 16):

Simply point the new repo by changing the GIT repo URL with this command:

```
git remote set-url origin [new repo URL]
```

Example: `git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:Batman/batmanRepoName.git`

Now, pushing and pulling are linked to the new REPO.

Then push normally like so:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 7):

This is has helped me to push my local project into a different repo on git

```
 git push https://github.com/yourusername/yourgithubproject.git master:master
```

Comment: clean; neat; works; simple

Answer (score 5):

Here is a manual way to do [`git remote set-url origin [new repo URL]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55908462/7259176):

1. Clone the repository: `git clone <old remote>`
2. Create a GitHub repository
3. Open `<repository>/.git/config`

   ```
   $ git config -e
   ```

   ```
   [core]
       repositoryformatversion = 0
       filemode = false
       bare = false
       logallrefupdates = true
       symlinks = false
       ignorecase = true
   [remote "origin"]
       url = <old remote>
       fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
   [branch "master"]
       remote = origin
       merge = refs/heads/master
   ```

   and change the remote (the url option)

   ```
   [remote "origin"]
       url = <new remote>
       fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
   ```
4. Push the repository to GitHub: `git push`

You can also use both/[multiple remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3195446/7259176).

Answer (score 5):

#### Link a local repository to a different remote repository

1- **Delete all connection with the remote repository**:
Inside the project folder:

- `git rm .git` (Remove all data from local repository)
- `git status` (I must say that it is not linked to any, something like an error)

2- **Link to a new remote repository**

- `git init` To start a local repository
- `git remote add origin urlrepository.git` To link with remote repository
- `git remote -v` To confirm that it is linked to the remote repository

3- **Add changes to the local repository and push to the remote repository**

- `git pull` or `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories` if git history is different in both local and remote repo.
- `git add.`
- `git commit -m" Message "`
- `git push -u origin master`

that's it!

Comment: Careful of deleting the .git directory. All data means all git data, even the git history. I already had some scenarios where i really need to check why something was done. This is not possible anymore if the .git directory is deleted.

Answer (score 5):

First, create your repo on Github. Then change directory to the checked-out source repository - suppose you want to push the `master` branch. You need to execute 5 simple steps:

```
git remote add origin2 https://github.com/user/example.git
git checkout master
git pull
git push origin2 master
git remote remove origin2
```

This creates the link between your local repo and the new remote, check out and pulls the source branch (to ensure that it has the latest), then pushes the current branch, finally unlinks the local repo from the remote.

Your local repo will be intact after this, you can use it as before. If you need to push multiple branches, repeat the `checkout`-`pull`-`push` steps as many times as you need, just change the branch name accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

To push an existing repository from the command line

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/AyadiAkrem/teachandgo.git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

Answer (score 3):

The way I've accomplished this is:

1. Create a new repo on github (new-repo.git)
2. `cd old-repo/` on local machine and fetch all new changes
3. `git push -u https://github.com/[username]/new-repo.git main -f`
4. Clone your new remote repo `https://github.com/[username]/new-repo.git` to your local environment

I've found this a simple way to essentially copy an old remote repo into a new remote repo.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem.

In my case, since I have the original repository in my local machine, I have made a copy in a new folder without any hidden file (.git, .gitignore).

Finally I have added the .gitignore file to the new created folder.

Then I have created and added the new repository from the local path (in my case using GitHub Desktop).

Answer (score 2):

**Visual studio 2022 and default git extension works flawlessly without even need for a single line of command.**

Step 1: Go to git settings

[image]

Step 2: Add new origin pointing to different repository in git/azure

[image]
[image]

Step 3: Now you have option to push to new origin in different repository in git/azure

[image]

Now there is a new branch in new repository
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to duplicate your GitHub repository so that you have two identical repositories on GitHub:

> git clone [existing-github-repo-url]

> git remote add duplicate [new-github-repo-url]

> git push duplicate master