# Migrating from Assembla to GitHub

Tags: git, version-control, github

My company has recently decided to switch to GitHub from Assembla (using git).  How would I duplicate the repository that is on Assembla in GitHub?

Comment: @LakshmanPrasad Absolutely, but it did not come up in my serach.

Comment: Did you find solution to migrate tickets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5181968/620197).  It was a simple matter of re-naming the origin to upstream then adding an origin pointing to GitHub.