# Pushing a repo to a new repo

Tags: git, github

[Git push existing repo to a new and different remote repo server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181845/git-push-existing-repo-to-a-new-and-different-remote-repo-server)

So I followed the instruction of the answer in this question, but I'm encountering some problems.

When I push to the completely fresh one it gets stuck for a couple of seconds at: Writing objects: ~60%:

[image: Screenshot]

In addition to that it also seems like I lose my internet for the couple of seconds. I don't have any issues if the files are not linked to any repos.

I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Copy and paste your error message into this question please. Did you try searching for the error message on Google or Stack Overflow? It sounds like it might just be a temporary network issue. Also, how big is your `.git` folder?

Comment: Well the thing is, it works if the files are not linked to any repo, but if they are, it bugs out like that. The folder is about 300mb.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I found a solution that at least work for what I initial wanted. All I did was deleting the hidden .git folder (was around 250mb). I then proceeded to do a git init and then push the files to the desired repository. I found other people suggestion to switch to ssh, so that might be an option for another person getting the same error, it wasn't an option for me however.

Comment: This makes very little sense. Deleting `.git` and then doing `git init` basically throws away all of your previous history...is that something that you really wanted to do?

Comment: Not really, but there doesn't seem to be anything else I can do to fix the issue, except for switching to ssh.