# How to push into a repository different from the repository I'm pulling from

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have cloned a public github repo and started modifying some of the files locally.

Now I'd like to commit and push these changes into a private repository, but still be able to pull and merge changes from the public repo.

How can I setup git for doing that ?

I know I could fork the public project and work off the forked version, but I am not going to merge my changes into the public repo, so I don't think it's the correct solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git push existing repo to a new and different remote repo server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181845/git-push-existing-repo-to-a-new-and-different-remote-repo-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the remote origin to the private repo:

```
git remote delete origin
git remote add origin git@server:user/repo.git
```

Now you can push to the private repo using

```
git push origin BRANCH_NAME
```

---

To pull (and merge) from the public repo I would create another remote, lets call it `upstream`:

```
git remote add upstream git@server:public/repo.git
```

You are now able to fetch from the upstream:

```
git fetch upstream master
```

and probably merge it into your local branch:

```
git merge upstream/BRANCH_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks fot the detailed answer ! The dot at the end of the last command line is unecessary though

Answer (score 1):

You can define multiple remote repositories.

```
$ git remote add repo1 <repo1_url>
$ git remote add repo2 <repo2_url>
```

Now you have 2 remote repos, lets say you are on `master` branch of `repo1` you can `git pull` directly if your branch is tracking the remote `master` branch then you can push to the other repo using

```
$ git push repo2 <branch_name>
```

now you have the branch pushed to the other repo.

Answer (score 1):

> I know I could fork the public project and work off the forked version, but I am not going to merge my changes into the public repo, so I don't think it's the correct solution.

It is a valid solution, even if you don't intent to make any pull-request.

It would not be a valid solution in case you don't want your changes to be visible (in a public repo, like the fork repo would be)

In that case, create an empty private repo (on Bitbucket for instance) and:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin /url/to/private/repo
git push --mirror
```

It is important to keep a link to the original public repo (here referenced as 'upstream') in order to be able to fetch or rebase on `upstream/master` (and getting the latest updates from that repo).