# Copying gh-pages branch from one repository to another repository

Tags: git, github, github-pages

My GitHub org is https://github.com/Obrary. There, I have 100s of open designs for products. Each is a project. I want each to have a GitHub page for the project.

I created a simple GitHub page for one of the projects. See http://obrary.github.io/Alex-Chair/. The page is created so that I can add it to any projects gh-pages branch and it will work for the new project. To see that in action, http://obrary.github.io/Alexey-Surfboard-Rack/.

Now I want to copy the gh-pages branch from /Alex-Chair to all my other projects.  In going through the help and examples, I've seen a lot of information about copying branches with a repo or copying repos in whole.  But I haven't found examples on how to copy a branch from repo A to repo B.

Here's the current command line that I've got.  But it fails because the clone command only works at the repo level (or so I think).

```
    git checkout --orphan gh-pages
    git rm --cached -r .
    git clone --bare https://github.com/Obrary/Alex-Chair/tree/gh-pages
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

First make sure there is a `gh-pages` branch in the repo you want to push to.

From the Alex-Chair gh-pages branch:

`git push -f [new repo url] gh-pages`

Or, add a new remote like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181845/git-push-existing-repo-to-a-new-and-different-remote-repo-server): (using Obrary/memes as an example)

```
git remote add memes https://github.com/Obrary/memes
git push --force memes gh-pages
```

You want to be [careful](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/04/force-with-lease/) with `force`, but in this case what you want to do (completely override the upstream with local files) is exactly what force will do.

Hope that helps!