# How do I push a new repo to a remote?

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to "publish" a local repository to a github enterprise server when the repo does not exist yet on the server?

#### Clarification

There have been some answers about various ways to move a repository to GitHub that all start with "create a repository on GitHub". I was looking for a way to create the repository remotely (i.e. by *not* going to GitHub). The answer related to using the API was the sort of thing I was looking for conceptually. However, I was hoping a quick easy way to do this and it looks like just going out to GitHub is the best/most efficient method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push existing repo to a new and different remote repo server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181845/git-push-existing-repo-to-a-new-and-different-remote-repo-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the repo using [GitHub's REST api](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create).

```
POST /user/repos
```

After the repo is created, you can [add a remote to it locally and push](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/).

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there just some git (ish) command to run, but looks like I now know to just go create the repo on the server first. I did investigate using *curl* or *wget* to use the API, but trying to deal with the domain login was taking too long.

Answer (score 0):

Open github account - create new repo and follow the instructions.

REad here how to do it.

https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/

Comment: Thanks for the link but I was asking if there was a way to push a new repo up to github. I believe the REST api is what I'm looking for.