# how do I push existing modified repository to new rep?

Tags: git

I followed the steps here [git-push-existing-repo-to-a-new-and-different-remote-repo-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181845/git-push-existing-repo-to-a-new-and-different-remote-repo-server)

But I have modified some file in upstream and I don't have permission to push to it, so I want to push it to a new rep, called origin.

Git tells me that I have unstaged changes, so what should I do next ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add all your files and than you can push

```
# add all your changes
git add .

# commit your changes
git commit -m "Message"
```

Now you will be able to pull your changes. Than add a new remote and push the merged branch to your second remote

```
# pull changes into the current branch
git pull origin master

# now push the changes
git push upstream master
```

Comment: But I don't have permission to push to upstream, that's the point