# How to push local repository to a different remote repository?

Tags: git, github

I cloned a remote repository (from github) locally.

Now I want to push that local repository, to a different remote repository (that already exists). How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push existing repo to a new and different remote repo server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181845/git-push-existing-repo-to-a-new-and-different-remote-repo-server)

Comment: Read about [`git remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) and [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you're talking about empty repo you have created on your github (usually `origin`). If it's empty, you can simply:

`git push <remote-branch> HEAD`

I wrote `HEAD` even though you're most probably on your local `master`. The difference is that `HEAD` is always pushing the branch you're currently on. It can be `master` or ANY other branch.

Btw, there is amazing book which covers this and much much more advanced topics and best of all - it's free:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Enjoy the learning :)