# Push to Github Visual Studio Community Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, github

I've been trying to setup a GitHub repository for a Xamarin iOS project that I'm doing on my Mac.

When creating the project, this is the settings I chose
[Setup Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u8A8.jpg)

However on I haven't been able to push to the GitHub repo I want to, I've tried to follow Microsoft's guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/set-up-git-repository but it hasn't worked due to [Publish in version control being greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gd3s2.png)

Answer (score 1):

Or, if your project is already bound to a git repository, simply add the GitHub remote and push it there.

```
git remote add github URL_TO_GITHUB_REPO
git push github master
```

Afterwards, Visual Studio should allow you to push to Github as well as any older remotes that were added locally.

You can always remove the existing remote if you want to:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote rename github origin
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52052063/736079

Answer (score 0):

Before publishing your project to GitHub from Visual Studio, you must remove any source control :

> If you have an existing project **that is
>   not already in version control**, use the following steps to set it up
>   in Git

Removing the .git folder and .gitgnore file should be enough. Then the "Publish in version control..." menu will be available (you might need to restart Visual Studio).

Source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/set-up-git-repository?view=vsmac-2019#publishing-an-existing-project