# Create new repo from Github template

Tags: git, github

I have created a repo designated as a template on Github that I'm trying to use as the basis for a new project so that I can reduce initial project startup time for projects with the same functionality.

Every time I clone that template to my local machine under a new project name, it is still associated with that original template and any commits will go there.

I've tried different variations of clone, meteor-boilerplate is what I'm trying to use as to begin an application called notes.
git clone https://github.com/ajsingh4/meteor-boilerplate.git notes

Would appreciate any advice as to how I can use that template as the basis for a new project in a separate repository.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5181845 etc.

Comment: Change the remote origin

Comment: Ok so from what I'm understanding
1) Create new repo on Github, from the template repo
2) Clone the repo locally
3) Change the remote origin via something such as 
git remote set-url origin URL_TO_NEW_REPO
Please let me know if I've misunderstood something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this via
1) Creating a new repo on Github using the template
2) Clone new repo locally
3) Change the remote URL to the new repo

Answer (score 1):

If you have created a [GitHub template repository](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-template-repository), then you don't clone it directly.

You [create a new one from template](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-repository-from-a-template), directly on the GitHub site.

Then you clone that new repository: you won't have to change its remote URL, it will already be the correct one.

Comment: If I don't change the remote URL, then for some reason, it still commits to the old repo. For some reason, changing the remote URL fixes that issue.

Comment: If you cli e a new repository created on GitHub, the remote URL will be the one of that repository.