# Github- Can't we create two repositories with same code

Tags: github, repository

I recently working in a project and I want to make two repositories with same code. So I duplicate one and tried to insert into git as a new repository. But it directed to the old repositories and committed there. 
Any help from someone please.

Comment: When you duplicate it, did you remember to exclude the git folder?

Comment: @Martheen should I want to delete git folder before making new repository? I do not know about that

Comment: If you don''t want to keep any git commit history, delete it on the new repo folder. If you want to keep them but commit to different repo, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181845/git-push-existing-repo-to-a-new-and-different-remote-repo-server

Comment: @Martheen That means, imagine I have **project1** folder and I made a git repo and added it. Then I want the same code slightly change for another project, So I create **project2** folder and insert **project1** folder itself to it. So I want to push **project2** folder as a new repo to git. So all I want to delete the .git folder in /project2/project1 , right? and again start with **git init**. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, assuming you really don't care about maintaining commits between those two repos. Otherwise @JustinBeckwith answer is a better option.

Comment: @Martheen ok. Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working in a single directory on your machine, and want to push code to multiple GitHub repositories, that's totally possible.  What you're looking for is multiple [remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes).

When you did a `git clone`, it probably created a `origin` remote that looks like `git@github.com:JustinBeckwith/linkinator.git`.

To see the remotes you already have, try:

```
$ git remote -v
```

To add a second remote, first find the URI on the second GitHub repository you want to use:
[image: Using the clone button on GitHub]

Copy that URI, and add it to your existing repository with:

```
$ git remote add second git@github.com:JustinBeckwith/linkinator-2.git
```

You could then push code by saying:

```
$ git push second master
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: **git push second master** means is this creating another branch in existing repository?

Comment: @KamalkaFernando No, that's different repository.

Comment: @JustinBeckwith **git remote add second git@link-of-new-repository** ,Is it? I am asking every single thing as I messed up my project while making new repository and I am afraid of typing git code. So please be patient to answer my questions.Thank you!

Comment: isn't the default branch of all newly created repos "main" and not "master"? using master gave error. **git push second main** should do the trick in case some gets the following error.

`error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/someone/something.git'`