# How to backup online Azure DevOps source control and restore to an instance of on-premises Azure DevOps Server

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to determine how to backup the online ADO account that I created on Microsoft's servers so that I can restore it on my own physical server.  I have a few projects already started along with work items, repositories, pipeline jobs and NuGet artifacts already in place.  It would take quite a while to rebuild the projects manually, not impossible, just not desirable.

I have looked and have not found any resource as to how to perform this or if it is even possible.  Any help from someone who knows would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is available extension: [Azure DevOps Migration Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration), which allow you to migrate Teams, Work Items, Plans & Suits, and Shared Queries, & Pipelines from one Project to another in Azure DevOps/TFS both within the same Organization, and between Organizations. See: https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/ for latest guidance.

In addition, for repositories, there is no such extensions, you could try to [clone an existing Git repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/clone?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio) and then [push it to a new remote repo server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181845/git-push-existing-repo-to-a-new-and-different-remote-repo-server).

BTW, you could use Rest APIs: [Artifact Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact%20%20details?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to get artifacts and then publish them to new feed on Azure DevOps Server.